# Define a New function like Log

Tags: function-construction

I want some help here. I want to define a function called Lg[z] that has the property that 
Lg[a/b] is always converted automatically to the form Lg[a] - Lg[b] , when a and b are polynomials of some variable say t.

I tried many things nothing works. I don't want to replace one by one by hand as it takes too long.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This could be a start, but it performs the transformation irrespective of whether `a` and `b` are polynomials in `t` or not.

```
ClearAll[Lg];
Lg[HoldPattern[Times[a__]]] := Plus @@ Lg /@ {a};
Lg[HoldPattern[Power[a_, p_]]] := p  Lg[a];
```

Here a few usage examples:

```
Lg[a b]
Lg[a/ b]
Lg[a^p]
Lg[Sum[t^k, {k, 0, 3}]/ Sum[k t^k, {k, 0, 3}]]
```

> Lg[a] + Lg[b]
>
> Lg[a] - Lg[b]
>
> p Lg[a]
>
> Lg[1 + t + t^2 + t^3] - Lg[t + 2 t^2 + 3 t^3]

One could make the patterns more restrictive with `PolynomialQ`, but maybe this already suffices for your task?

Comment: what's the advantage of using a `HoldPattern`?

Comment: @Roman: the pattern `Times[a__]` evaluates to `a__` during the assignment in `SetDelayed`, so if you don't use `HoldPattern`, you won't get the correct downvalues.

Comment: I see, thanks! A bit simpler would be `Lg[a_*b_] = Lg[a] + Lg[b]` and `Lg[a_^p_] = p*Lg[a]`.

Comment: @Roman - Henrik's approach is more efficient for more complicated arguments. Compare timings for `Lg[a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z]`

Comment: @BobHanlon yes Henrik's is much faster because mine relies on recursion. Cheers!

Comment: This is all well and good, but the newly defined `Lg` does not share the properties of `Log`. Is there a way to create a new function `Lg` which shares almost all of the properties of `Log` (i.e. *Mathematica* can evaluate it numerically) but just has this one difference that it expands a product argument to a sum of `Lg`? I think that would be more in the spirit of the question, and more useful for most users.